# How to make sure the sql result is continued range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like:

```
id   | low_number | high_number
-------------------------------
1    |  12        | 32
-------------------------------
2    |  13        | 33
-------------------------------
3    |   15       | 36
-------------------------------
4    |   33       |  50 
-------------------------------
5    |   35       | 52
...
-------------------------------
17   |   52       |  80
```

I want to get result like:

```
id   | low_number | high_number
-------------------------------
1    |  12        | 32
-------------------------------
4    |   33       |  50 
-------------------------------
17   |   52       |   80
```

that is because the low_number bigger than the pervious row high_number.

How to write sql to get these result? I use postgresql

Comment: It is not very clear what you try to achieve and the example I think is too simplistic. What if id 4 would have low_number 34? What output do you expect then?

Comment: as long as low_number larger than the pervious line high_number it will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a recursive CTE problem.  You want to choose the first row (by id) and then choose the next row based on that.

The idea is to cycle through the rows, one at a time.  Then when the condition is met, transition to that row.  And so on.

As a query, this looks like:

```
with recursive tt as (
      select id, low_number, high_number, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, low_number, high_number, seqnum, true as is_change, id as grouping_id
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.id, tt.low_number, tt.high_number, tt.seqnum, tt.low_number > t.high_number,
             (case when tt.low_number > t.high_number then tt.id else cte.grouping_id end)
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.grouping_id = t.id join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte
where is_change;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c215657860b0ce99446e78e1915aff8b) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the window function `LAG()` to get a value of a previous row, e.g.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    id,low_number,high_number, 
    LAG(high_number) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prev_high_number
  FROM t)
SELECT id,low_number,high_number  FROM j
WHERE low_number > prev_high_number OR prev_high_number IS NULL;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cec0d4fb13108ae58c0d7a4c375fcdd5)

Comment: I find  your result only contain 2 rows, while my expect is need 3 rows.

Comment: @user504909 you said yourself `ow_number larger than the pervious line high_number it will accept ` and it does exactly this